# error when trying to start hadoop via php

Tags: php, linux, shell

i have a shell script, that is start-dfs.sh. it runs well when using terminal.i want to execute it via php and i tried the following code in php:

```
<?php
$output= shell_exec("/usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/start-dfs.sh");

echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>" ;

?>
```

when i execute the code above i get the error:

> Starting namenodes on [localhost]
>   localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
>   Starting datanodes
>   localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
>   Starting secondary namenodes [chbpc-VirtualBox]
>   chbpc-VirtualBox: Permission denied (publickey,password).

how can i resolve this?

Comment: If you execute that script through a browser, it will be the user that runs the web server (usually www-data for Apache) that will execute that command. That user usually have very limited permissions on the system (for good reasons).

Comment: is there any other way to execute this via my web page?